# Group by with normal fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using this query

```
select id, name, parent_id
from table_p
group by parent_id
having count(parent_id) > 1
```

So the problem with this is I need to put id and name in an aggregate function. Sorry for asking such basic question, but is there a way in which I can avoid this and print ids with duplicate parent_id in a single query?

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to print parent_id too?

Comment: I want result like id,name,parent_id

Comment: Anyways both the answers work. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a window function that counts the number of siblings:

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id) cnt
FROM table_p
```

then you can just use a subquery:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM (
  SELECT id, name, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id) cnt
  FROM table_p
) s
WHERE cnt>1
```

Please see a fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6e4ad/1).

Comment: i think he wants to view parent_id also in result. but in second sql we cant view parent_id.

Comment: @ChamlyIdunil yes I didn't include it, but you can add any field on the select query, even select * if needed

Comment: but when we add parent_id into select clause it give error.

Answer (score 1):

Return a row if same parent_id exists for another row (one with different id value):

```
select id, name, parent_id
from table_p t1
where exists (select 1 from table_p t2
              where t2.parent_id = t1.parent_id
                and t2.id <> t1.id)
```

Comment: Although if in t2.parent_id = t1.parent_id, it were some string comparison, it would take ages to compute this query.

Comment: Is parent_id char? And no index? Well, maybe you should add table definitions to your question if you're afraid of performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

hope you can use this SQL

```
select id, name, parent_id 
from table_p 
where parent_id in (select parent_id
                    from table_p
                    group by parent_id
                    having count(parent_id) >1)
order by parent_id
```